# Vue js Server-Table with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm developing a web application for watching and managing data from my MongoDB. I'm using VueJS as the client side and NodeJS + Express + Mongoose in the server side (MEVN Stack).

I have tried to represent a table of my data in the client side, using the "vue-tables-2" (server-side) table and translate the http requests (Sort\Filter..) in the server to MongoDB query using "Querymen", but it seems the querymen fail to translate the Vue's http request.

The reason is that the Vue wrap the query's parameters with the "query" word:

http://localhost:3000/data?query%5BName%5D=Mor&query%5BLastName%5D=Vino&limit=10

While the querymen expect to receive:

http://localhost:3000/data?Name=Mor&LastName=Vino&limit=10

Did someone find a solution for that?
Or used different table component \ different translation library?

Versions: Vue js 2.5.16, Node js 8.11.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can customize request by using `requestAdapter` in options

```
requestAdapter(data) {
    // in here you can access data.query, split, concat or do anything you want
    return {
      Name: '' // put params here,
      LastName: '',
      limit: data.limit ? data.limit: 10
    }
  }
```

You can check [official demo](https://jsfiddle.net/matfish2/js4bmdbL/) for reference

Comment: Thank you. This does solve the problem but i prefer to find a generic solution (Without specifying the "Name","LastName").

Comment: You can split `data.query` and assign to return object dynamically